# Facebook Request(s): what counts as 1 request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently creating an application that polls facebook for data. First request a page in this fashion...

```
pageID/posts?fields=id,message,created_time,type&limit=250
```

This returns the top 250 posts from a page. I then check if there page next is set and if it is make another request for the next 250 posts. I continue this recursively until there are no more posts.

With each post that is returned I go out and fetch the post details from the graph api as well.

My question is if I had 500 posts on a page. Would that equate to 502 requests?  (500 requests for each post + 2 for parsing through page data to get posts) or am I incorrect in my understanding of a "request". I know when batching calls each query included in the batch actually counts as 1 request. The goal is to avoid the 600 calls / 600 second rate limiting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every API call is...well, 1 request. So every time you use the /posts endpoint with whatever limit, it will be 1 request. For example, if you do that call you posted, it will be one request that returns 250 elements.

Batch requests are just faster, but each call in the batch counts as a request. So if you combine 10 calls in a batch, it will be 10 requests. The benefit of batch calls is really just that they are a lot faster: as fast as the slowest call in the batch.

If you want to get 500 posts with that example of yours, you would only need 2 calls. First one with 250 returned elements, second one by using the API call defined in the "next" value to get another 250. Just keep in mind that the default is usually 25 elements, and you can´t use any limit you want. There is a max limit for calls and it gets changed from time to time afaik so don´t count on getting the same result every time.

Btw, don't be to fixated on that 600calls/600seconds limit, it's just a general limit. The real limit is dynamic and depends on many factors. It's not public, of course. But if you really hit the limit, you are doing something wrong anyway.

Comment: According to developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests "batch requests will be counted as a single request for rate limiting purposes.", but also "each call within the batch is counted separately for the purposes of calculating API call limits and resource limits". Not clear to me!